# SqlAlchemy dynamic query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SqlAlchemy as my interface to an Oracle database and I'm wondering if something is possible, and if so, how. I'm trying to build a query that gets data aggregates, but then add columns to the query dynamically based on parameters passed in with a Flask request. Here's an example query (simplified from my actual query):

```
db.session.query(
    func.count(Batch.batch_id).label('count'),
    Category.product_title.label('product_title'),
) \
.join(Category, Category.category_id == Batch.category_id)
.filter(Batch.date <= end_date) \
.filter(Batch.date >= start_date)
.group_by(Category.product_title)
.all()
```

This is kind of the starting point for my query. But based on request parameters I'd like to modify this basic query to look something like this as an extended query:

```
LateB = db.aliased(Batch)

db.session.query(
    func.count(Batch.batch_id).label('count'),
    func.count(distinct(LateB.batch_id).label('late'),
    Category.product_title.label('product_title'),
) \
.join(Category, Category.category_id == Batch.category_id) \
.outerjoin(LateB, (LateB.batch_id == Batch.batch_id) & (LateB.date <= some_date_in_the_past)) \
.filter(Batch.date <= end_date) \
.filter(Batch.date >= start_date)
.group_by(Category.product_title)
.all()
```

My goal is to create the basic query, but then to dynamically modify it so it ends up looking like the extended query. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: It's possible, use for example [`Query.add_colums()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.add_columns).

Comment: This worked once I figured out how to add the "func.count(....)" that I wanted. Thanks!